# ES6 - exporting index.js from module and circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, circular-dependency

I have multiple modules in my react/redux app, let's say:

```
root:
|-- moduleA
|-- moduleB
|-- moduleC
|-- ...
```

They all have similar shape:

```
moduleX
|-- components
|-- containers
|-- actions.js
|-- reducers.js
|-- index.js
```

And moduleA needs few actions from moduleB, but moduleB also needs few actions from moduleA. They use actions from another module, because they sometimes have to modify state (redux store) of another module. It is business logic, and I don't want to duplicate parts of the store.

All modules have index.js file, they export actions, reducers and main container. But importing index.js from moduleA in moduleB and index.js from B inn A leads to circular dependencies:

```
ERROR in Circular dependency detected:
src/moduleA/containers/Container.jsx -> 
src/moduleB/index.js -> 
src/moduleB/containers/Container.jsx -> 
src/moduleA/index.js -> 
src/moduleA/containers/Container2.jsx -> 
src/moduleA/containers/Container3.jsx -> 
src/moduleA/containers/Container.jsx
```

And few more errors reported by circular-dependency-plugin.

I wonder, how can I import only actions from moduleB index.js in moduleA? Now, as workaround, I use this pattern:

```
import * as moduleBActions from "../path/to/moduleB/actions"
```

Is there any other way? I have to export containers in index.js, because they are part of the module API and I use them in router configuration. I don't want to duplicate parts of the store (each module have own branch in state object)

Comment: had the same problem yesterday, I think that manually importing the actions file is a good choice. Also you should remove the action file export from the `index.js` to avoid getting the same problem in the future.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am seeing the same issue when bundling my code in production, but not when using hotmodulereplacement. It seems to drag all the files in from the index regardless of what module was named in the import.

Comment: For now I import actions directly from module/actions.js file and I removed them from index.js of that module.